# Can I improve this mysql query for speed?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm using testlink for our internal storage system for testing.  The following query takes almost 80 seconds and returns about 11k rows of data.  Is there anything that jumps out that I can improve on?  I'm assuming it's the two left outer joins that are the bottleneck.

Current Speed:

```
(11,002 total, Query took 82.8888 sec)
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT UA.build_id AS build_id, 
   UA.feature_id AS feature_id,
   UA.user_id as user_id,   
   TPTCV.testplan_id AS testplan_id,
   TPTCV.tcversion_id AS tcversion_id,
   TPTCV.platform_id AS platform_id,       
   E.status AS status,
   E.id as execution_id,
   E.tester_id as tester_id
FROM user_assignments UA  
LEFT OUTER JOIN testplan_tcversions TPTCV ON UA.feature_id = TPTCV.id  
LEFT OUTER JOIN executions E ON TPTCV.tcversion_id = E.tcversion_id
AND UA.build_id = E.build_id
AND TPTCV.platform_id = E.platform_id
WHERE UA.type = 1 AND UA.build_id = 10
ORDER BY E.id DESC
```

Comment: Without an idea of your table definitions, this is a hard-to-answer question.

Comment: Please post which columns are indexed plus an execution plan and you will likely get much better answers.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have indices on the foreign key columns? You need them. On all join columns, if possible. Also generate an execution plan and see the output, this is very helpful for performance analysis. Post it here if you do not understand it.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/execution-plan-information.html

Your ORDER BY clause also is likely to be very expensive. Avoid it. Sort elsewhere, if possible.

Comment: thanks, that saved a few seconds.

Comment: What else does your execution plan say?

Comment: I'll take some time and generate an execution plan and post it in a new thread. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, ok. Also have a look at the workbench, which might help you as well. http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding covering indexes, so the query can be satisfied entirely from the index blocks, without need to reference table blocks.

e.g.

```
... ON user_assignments (build_id, type, feature_id, user_id)

... ON testplan_tcversions (id, testplan_id, tcversion_id, platform_id)

... ON executions (tcversion_id, platform_id, build_id,  status, tester_id, id)
```

You can also try running the query without the ORDER BY, to remove the need for a sort operation.